# ¿Cómo saber si un archivo regular no existe en bash?

Tags: bash, archivo

Supongamos que estoy en un directorio y sé que un archivo `archivo` existe:

```
if [ -f "archivo" ]; then
    echo "archivo existe"
fi
```

¿Hay alguna manera de comprobar si el archivo *no* existe sin tener que utilizar el `else` de este condicional?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/638975/1983854

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<sub>Extraído de la pregunta hermana [How do I tell if a regular file does not exist in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/638980/1983854).</sub>

¡Sí! Solo tienes que utilizar la negación `!` en el condicional:

```
if [ ! -f "archivo" ]; then
    echo "archivo no existe"
fi
```

O de una forma más concisa:

```
[ ! -f "archivo" ] && echo "archivo regular no existe"
```

---

Nótese que `man test` indica que la opción `-f`:

```
-f FILE
     FILE exists and is a regular file
```

Por lo que la negación de esto simplemente quiere decir que lo indicado no es un archivo regular. Puede no ser nada o puede ser un directorio, etc.

Comment: Yo añadiría también que la forma correcta de comprobar si un fichero, del tipo que sea, no existe es `[ ! -e "archivo" ]`.

Comment: Hola ¿No consideras convertir tu respuesta como Wiki de comunidad?

Comment: @Jorgesys no, ¿por? [¿Deben marcarse como wiki de comunidad las traducciones de contenido?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2660/83)

Comment: Se que es opcional, solo que no había notado que tu mismo realizaste la pregunta y la respondiste (1 dic. 15 a las 16:58) por eso preguntaba.

Comment: @Jorgesys sí, fue en el primer momento del Beta con el furor de traer contenido de SO. Dudé hace unos meses, pregunté en Meta y vi que hay bastante consenso en no marcar como wiki a menos que se quiera explicitar que es algo para mejorar entre todos. Dado que la respuesta es bastante estándar y no cambiará (Bash es muy antiguo) creo que no hace falta. Eso sí, si genera confusión o malestar no tengo problema en marcarla como tal. Saludos.

Answer (score 10):

Se puede utilizar la negación `!` antes del `-f`

```
if [ ! -f "$archivo" ]; then
    echo "archivo inexistente"
fi
```

o antes del `[`

```
if ! [ -f "$archivo" ]; then
    echo "archivo inexistente"
fi
```

También se puede utilizar `-e` de esta forma

```
if [ ! -e "$archivo" ]; then
   echo "archivo inexistente"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Este es el script que uso para revisar si un archivo existe:

```
if [ ! -f "/miFolder/miArchivo.txt" ]; then
    echo "El archivo no existe"
fi
```

la opción `-f` es negada para determinar no existe el archivo.

Comment: Hola Jorge, estaba revisando esta pregunta mía de hace tanto tiempo... Me doy cuenta que de hecho utilizas lo mismo que sugerí en mi respuesta. Pero hay un par de detalles que deberían corregirse aquí: es importante utilizar comillas alrededor del nombre del archivo, para que así los nombres con espacios se gestionen bien; además, `echo " ... !!"` da error, pues al estar `!!` entre comillas dobles intenta expandirse al anterior comando. Por tanto, es preferible usar comillas simples.

Comment: Revisando estsa respuesta (recibí un voto positivo en mi pregunta) me doy cuenta que ahora esta respuesta es exactamente igual a la aceptada (mía)