# Como validar si un archivo existe o no, cuando el nombre del archivo cambia

Tags: linux, script, shell-script, centos7

Estoy validando si un archivo existe o no a través de if, pero este funciona cuando el nombre del fichero no cambia, pero mi problema es que el archivo cambia de nombre, ya que sale de un proceso de export, donde se extrae nombredelarchivo-fechayhora.sql :
Hay alguna forma de hacer esto con un if-else.? o alguna otra manera

saque solo la parte que valida el archivo, ya que es muy extenso el scritp.
De esta manera no valida nada, ya que el archivo esta, pero manda el eco de "no existe"

> script

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f "/home/*.sql" ];
then
echo "no existe"
else
echo "si existe"
fi
```

> fin

Comment: podés poner lo que hiciste? Se me ocurre que podrias usar un comodin y/o una clave en el nombre de los archivos de salida. Ej, le agregas ``salida_``: salida_nombredelachivo-fechayhora.sql, entonces harias algo como ``find /directorio -name "salida_*.sql"``

Comment: Ayuda mucho si agregas tu script para poderte apoyar

Answer (score 0):

para simplificar el scritp, la parte que valida es simple. Esto me funciona cuando el archivo tiene un nombre fijo.

FILE="/home/archivo.sql"
if [ -f $FILE ]
then
echo "HAY FICHEROS A EXPORTAR!"
else
echo "NO HAY FICHEROS A EXPORTAR!"
fi

Comment: esto fallaría si el fichero tiene espacios, necesitas poner comillas dobles `[ -f "$FILE" ]`. En cualquier caso, esto ya está indicado en [¿Cómo saber si un archivo regular no existe en bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/74/83). También recomendable no usar variables en mayúscula para no provocar problemas con variable de entorno y de la shell

Comment: claro, pero no los tiene. el proceso que dispara el archivo.sql, lo deja de esta manera, archivo-fechayhora.sql.  Trate de validarlo así, pero no funciona, pasa directo al else indicando que no hay archivo.                                                                                                              #!/bin/bash
file="/home/*.sql"
if [ -f "$file" ];
then
wget -O http://xxxxxxxxxx > /dev/null;
else
echo "No hay datos a procesar"
fi

Comment: dale a [edit] para poner los detalles en la publicación, pues en comentarios no se ve bien.

Comment: @JosePavez te recomiendo que realices el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) ya que si quieres agregar más detalles a tu pregunta solo la [edites](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/468828/edit) y no lo agregues como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez puedas realizar el script de la siguiente manera:

```
for FILE in $(find archivo-*.sql; do
  # Realizar las tareas con ${FILE}
done
```

Así, si no se encuentra el archivo ya no se ejecuta el interior del bucle.

Puedes crear alguna variable a modo de flag que indique que ha entrado en el bucle por si lo necesitas.

Comment: gracias, voy a probar y comento.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás comprobando si existe y es un fichero regular (opción -f del comando test de bash) el archivo llamado exactamente ***.sql** (esto es por las comillas). Cuando lo que creo que querés es buscar cualquier archivo con extensión **.sql**. Al estar entrecomillado, el **comodín *** no se expande.

Si le sacás las comillas, el script funciona siempre y cuando en el directorio tengas solo un archivo con extensión **.sql**, a pesar de que el nombre del archivo tenga espacios.

Te sugiero que no uses lógica negativa, sino que busques si el archivo **si existe**.

Si querés que el script te funcione cuando tengas uno o más archivos con extensión **.sql**, podés usar este script que te escribí.

```
#!/bin/bash

ls /home/*.sql &> /dev/null

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
  echo "si existe"
else
  echo "no existe"
fi
```

Es similar, pero lo que hace es pedir un listado de los nombres que terminen con **.sql** y posteriormente comprueba el resultado que devuelve el comando **ls**, que será **0** solo en el caso de encontrar al menos un archivo de esas características.

Espero que te sirva, el tema del shell son las configuraciones de cada distribución, a veces algunas cosas pueden comportarse distinto, pero creo que te va a funcionar. Yo lo comprobé con mi distro (gentoo) y funciona perfecto.

**Nota:** Te sugiero que estudies el comando **test** del shell y posteriormente te dediques con paciencia al estudio de las **expresiones regulares (regex)**, te va a servir para entender estas situaciones y no conformarte con el *copy/paste*.